# combine a list with &&

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a huge list of the form

```
{a==1,b==2}
```

I want to get the expression like

```
a==1&&b==2
```

How is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `@@` (a.k.a `Apply`):

```
And@@{a==1,b==2}
```

> a == 1 && b == 2